# Return dynamic table with unknown NUMBER of columns from PL/pgSQL function

Tags: postgresql, function, crosstab

I have a table skills that contains one list skills:

```
CREATE TABLE common.skill (
    skill_id bigint NOT NULL,
    skill_description character varying(255),
    skill_name character varying(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO common.skill VALUES (4, NULL, 'Excel');
INSERT INTO common.skill VALUES (5, NULL, 'Microsoft Office');
INSERT INTO common.skill VALUES (6, NULL, 'Contabilidad');
INSERT INTO common.skill VALUES (7, NULL, 'Tributo y Aduanas');
INSERT INTO common.skill VALUES (3, NULL, 'Administracíon');
```

I have a table skill_job that contains all the skills needed for one particular Job.

```
CREATE TABLE job.skill_job (
    skill_id bigint NOT NULL,
    requirement character varying(255),
    job_id bigint NOT NULL
);

insert into job.skill_job (skill_id, requirement, job_id) values (3, 1, 1);
insert into job.skill_job (skill_id, requirement, job_id) values (1, 2, 2);
insert into job.skill_job (skill_id, requirement, job_id) values (3, 2, 3);
insert into job.skill_job (skill_id, requirement, job_id) values (1, 2, 4);
insert into job.skill_job (skill_id, requirement, job_id) values (1, 2, 5);
insert into job.skill_job (skill_id, requirement, job_id) values (3, 1, 6);
insert into job.skill_job (skill_id, requirement, job_id) values (1, 1, 7);
insert into job.skill_job (skill_id, requirement, job_id) values (1, 1, 8);
insert into job.skill_job (skill_id, requirement, job_id) values (1, 2, 9);
insert into job.skill_job (skill_id, requirement, job_id) values (1, 2, 10);
```

I want to return the data on the format below. For that, I can create the query in runtime (reading the skills table to get all the skills) and use crosstab to create a Pivot (skill ID as a colunm name):

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab( 
$$ select job_id, skill_id, requirement from job.skill_job order by job_id $$,
$$
  SELECT '3' UNION ALL
  SELECT '4' UNION ALL
  SELECT '5' UNION ALL
  SELECT '6' UNION ALL
  SELECT '7'
$$
)
AS ct(job_id NUMERIC, "3" NUMERIC, "4" NUMERIC, "5" NUMERIC, "6" NUMERIC, "7" NUMERIC);
```

[image]

**My problem is:** I need to create a function that returns this Pivot table and I don't know how many columns will be returned (it depends on the total number of skills on the SKILLS table)

Comment: NOTE: REQUIREMENT field could have one of these values: 1 - Mandatory;  2 - Desired

Comment: Not possible. A fundamental restriction of the SQL language is that all columns must be know to the database before the query is processed, i.e. when the query is parsed.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to return this as a row source ( = table)? The only reason I could foresee is that you have to further process the result in SQL. Otherwise, you could easily return the data as an array of `skill_id`s or a JSON of `skill_id`, `requirement` and `job_id` and then present the data on the client side in whatever format you need.

Comment: Instead of `SELECT '3' UNION ALL...` use `VALUES ('3'), ('4'),...`

Comment: @Patrick, it will be an input to AI algorithm